# Regex with + sign

Tags: php, regex

I'm using this code to validate string.

```
$countrecipient ='0123456789';

preg_match('/^[0]{1}[1]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{7}?$/', $countrecipient)
```

How if I want to validate if the number contain "+" sign in front or not?

Such as :

```
$countrecipient ='+0123456789';
```

and still need to validate the rest of the string.

I tried this:

```
 if(preg_match('/^[+]{1}[6]{1}[0]{1}[1]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{7}?$/', $countrecipient))
 {
   echo "Ok";
 }
 else
 {
   echo "Error";
 }
```

It works in my pc but I'm not sure why my customer is complaining it shows him error.

Thank you.

Comment: So... you haven't been able to reproduce the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an optional plus in front you could use:

```
preg_match('/^\+?[0]{1}[1]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{7}?$/', $countrecipient);
```

Notice how I have escaped the `+` with a backslash? This is because it is a regex keyword which means 1 instance or more.

Comment: Sorry for my late response and thanks for your answer . It works,thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
$countrecipient ='0123456789';
preg_match('/^[0]{1}[1]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{7}?$/', $countrecipient)
```

You're making things unnecessarily complicated.  "[0]{1}[1]{1}[0-9]{1}" reduces to simply "01[0-9]".

To have an optional + on the front, your basic idea of using [+] should work.  Let's see...

```
$countrecipient ='+0123456789';
if(preg_match('/^[+]{1}[6]{1}[0]{1}[1]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{7}?$/', $countrecipient))
```

...again this can be simplified, but it simplies to `/^[+]601[0-9][0-9]{7}?$/`.  Where did the `6` after the `+` come from?  Does this account for your problem?

Comment: I'm so sorry for my late response and thanks for your reply.Yes I just noticed that I made something unnecessarily...Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Plus has a special meaning in PCRE, it's called [quantifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php)  and has meaning of `{1,}`.

You may either put in into character group specification like this `[+]` which would literally mean `one of following characters: array( '+')` or escape it with `\` so you'll get: `\+`.

Also adding `{1}` is implicit and you don't have to add it after one character. If you were doing this matching `foo` would look like: `f{1}o{1}o{1}`, ehm `f{1}o{2}` instead of `foo` :)

If you want to match both `0123456789` **and** `+012345678` you should use `{0,1}` which has "shortcut" `?`. Than your pattern would look like: `/\+?/`. I **guess** your desired regexp is:

```
/^\+?0?1?[0-9]([0-9]{7})?$/
```

Comment: Sorry for my late response and Thanks for your answer,will learn it,thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The simplified form of your regex is

```
/\+?01[0-9]{8}/
```

However I recommend you use [intval](http://php.net/intval), [is_int](http://php.net/is_int), [ctype_digit](http://php.net/ctype_digit) to accomplish this.

```
if(intval($str)<=100000000){
    // found it.
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my late response and thanks for your advises. Will take a look to the function.

Answer (score 1):

Based on regexp you put in the section you tried: "...preg_match('/^[+]{1}[6]{1}[0]{1}[1]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{7}?$/'..."

If you would validate the string AND check if there is a '+' or not, you could use something like this:

```
if(preg_match('/(\+)?6011[0-9][0-9]{7}?$/', $countrecipient, $matches)) 
{
   if ($matches[1] == '+') {

      echo "Ok WITH PLUS";
   } else {
      echo "Ok without PLUS"; 
   }
}
else
{
   echo "Error";
}
```